# Passing a varible from jQuery to PHP

Tags: jquery, query-posts, ajax

I have a a bunch of li's that are a blog but i want to show them enlarged in a colorbox. Therefore I need to know which li I clicked so I can get that ID and use that in my query to get all the date for that post.

Now I thought that the best way is to retrieve the blog id with jQuery and then use that to add to my query in the footer.

```
    <li id="<?php the_ID;?>">blog</li>
    <li id="<?php the_ID;?>">blog</li>
    <li id="<?php the_ID;?>">blog</li>
    <li id="<?php the_ID;?>">blog</li>

    //My colorbox inline frame
    <?php query_posts( 'p="the_ID_of_clicked_li' ); ?>
     etc etc
```

I think this can be done with AJAX but is there a more simple method and give me a clean URL?

I haven't AJAX in projects before, so I am a beginner with that.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Hey Michiel, that's a pretty broad question.  If you do some searching you can find a lot of answers that give you a step by step for using ajax in WordPress, which is a little bit different than using it in a straight up app without a framework, although it's pretty much the same thing under the hood.  If you have a more specific question, you might get a more detailed answer here.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `query_posts`.

Second...

> I think this can be done with AJAX but is there a more simple method
>   and give me a clean URL?

PHP runs on the server. Items are "clicked" on the client machine. The only way to pass that "clicked" value back to PHP is via AJAX. Within a WordPress framework that mostly means using the WordPress [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

So, there is no more simple method than AJAX to get a "clicked" value back to PHP.

However, if your original PHP Loop prints the post body to the page and you hide it by default via CSS-- ie. `display:none`-- then your jQuery/Javascript can then selectively show/hide content and you don't need another request to the server at all. That may count as "more simple", if that is an option.

I don't know what "give me a clean URL" means in this context.